# Match strings with accents

Tags: php

I have a word (city name) that contains accented letters. I have a function that check if the city name is in an array, and if it is will return a value (if not wil lreturn another value).
The word won't match any city (with accent) in the array even if the city is there. I printed out both of them and they show properly (no weird characters instead of the accent).
What it might be?
thanks

```
function SearchPV($city){
require('PV_CAP_Array.php');

$city = str_replace(" ", "", $city);
$city = str_replace("\'","", $city);

    foreach($CAP_PV_ARRAY as $key=>$value){
        if(strtolower($city) ==  strtolower($key))
            return 'VR';
        else
            return "PV != VR";
    }
}
```

array:

```
$CAP_PV_ARRAY=array('affi'=>'37010',
                    'dolcè'=>'37020'
};
```

EDIT

I removed the else statement and it works (even if I don't know why). Seems like the return won't break the loop (it was going on evaluating the other options and returning "PV != VR"

working code

```
foreach($CAP_PV_ARRAY as $key => $value){
        if(strtolower($city) ==  strtolower($key))
            return "VR";
    }
```

Comment: Use [`mb_` prefixed string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) to work with unicode.

Comment: or regex that only allows normal letters eg `/[a-zA-Z\ \-]/`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `return` statement, in your original code:

```
function SearchPV($city) {
    require('PV_CAP_Array.php');

    $city = str_replace(" ", "", $city);
    $city = str_replace("\'","", $city);

    foreach($CAP_PV_ARRAY as $key=>$value){
        if(strtolower($city) ==  strtolower($key))
            return 'VR';
        else
            return "PV != VR";
    }
}
```

It will only ever check the first item in the array, as it will either return `VR` or `PV != VR` due to the `if`/`else`.  You *may* have intended to do something more like the following, where it will return `VR` if any of the entries match, or `PV != VR` otherwise:

```
function SearchPV($city) {
    require('PV_CAP_Array.php');

    $city = str_replace(" ", "", $city);
    $city = str_replace("\'","", $city);

    foreach($CAP_PV_ARRAY as $key=>$value){
        if(strtolower($city) ==  strtolower($key))
            return 'VR';
    }
    return "PV != VR";
}
```